# Magento Display Product Prices In Catalog is not working for including tax

Tags: magento-1.9, price, tax-class

I have a custom tax rule and the "Catalog Prices" is set to including tax.Then i have set the "Display Product Prices In Catalog" to including tax.But this is not working at all.In category page and product detail page it still showing the price without the tax.Why this happening? if anyone know please help me.I have used the following settings in admin->system->configuration->sales->tax

The settings are listed below :

```
1. Tax Calculation Method Based On :- Total 
2. Tax Calculation Based On :- Shipping address 
3. Catalog Prices :- including tax 
4. Shipping Prices :- including tax 
5. Cash on Delivery fee include tax :- yes 
6. Apply Customer Tax :- Before discount 
7. Apply Discount On Prices :- including tax 
8. Default Country :- Norway 
9. Display Product Prices In Catalog :- including tax 
10. Display Shipping Prices :- including tax 
11. Display Cod Fee :- including tax
```

thank you all.

Comment: How have you configured the tax rule and what are your complete tax settings?

Comment: i have created a tax rule with 25% tax rate.The settings are lsited below :
Tax Calculation Method Based On :- Total
Tax Calculation Based On :- Shipping address
Catalog Prices :- including tax
Shipping Prices :- including tax
Cash on Delivery fee include tax :- yes
Apply Customer Tax :- Before discount
Apply Discount On Prices :- including tax
Default Country :- Norway
Display Product Prices In Catalog :- including tax
Display Shipping Prices :- including tax
Display Cod Fee :- including tax

also in shopping cart its works fine.The shopping cart settings are correctly working

Comment: Can you edit your question and add the settings into it?

Comment: Yes Mr.Jonathan Hussey.I have added the settings to the question.Any solution for this.Help will be appreciated...

Comment: Thanks, what about for the tax rule?

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to set **Yes** in **Enable Cross Border Trade** from

> Admin > System > Configuration > Sales > Tax > Calculation settings

Comment: solved my problem.